# Apache Arrow getting vectors from Java in Python with zero copy

Tags: java, python, apache-arrow

I use Apache Arrow libraries in java (`arrow-vector`, `arrow-memory-unsafe`) and python (`pyarrow`) **in different processes**

I try to implement in memory zero copy DataFrame, but I can’t find appropriate API in java libraries to get memory address of arrow vectors from python. I have found that API in `pyarrow` library, but not in java libraries.

What I need:

1. create vector in java, collect data in memory using arrow as memory map API
2. **get memory address or descriptor of `VectorSchemaRoot` or field vectors in java**
3. pass it to the python library `pyarrow`
4. read apache arrow vector data

I have problem in the point **2**

Do you know how can I do that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is the `pyarrow.jvm` module for this. The following code should be sufficient to turn a `VectorSchemaRoot` into a `RecordBatch`:

```py
import pyarrow.jvm

vs_root = <VectorSchemaRoot>
rb = pyarrow.jvm.record_batch(vs_root)
```

This is how it works if you have a Python reference to the Java `VectorSchemaRoot`  object, e.g. by using `jpype` (see also https://uwekorn.com/2020/12/30/fast-jdbc-revisited.html for a full use of that for JDBC).

If you use a different approach, you will need to iterate over the arrays of the `VectorSchemaRoot` and then of the buffers of them to get the individual memory addresses of all buffers. These can then be used to construct Buffer objects on the `pyarrow` side and in return `pyarrow.Array` instances.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I do not have an opportunity to do it from python, I only can to use separate processes. First process is java for memory data writing and second is python for memory data reading. I assumed apache arrow can help me to use shared memory between processes using java unsafe

Comment: Ah, your question sounded like you were running in the same process as you want to have the memory address. Memory addresses are process-local and cannot be handed between processes unless you have specially allocated a shared memory section. This is probably worthwhile in your case. Then you can use the approach as above but you will first have to ensure that Java can write to that shared memory.